# HTML5 form validation pattern automatically create a space after first 3 characters?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Using the pattern attribute in HTML forms is it possible to create a space automatically after 3 characters? How can this be accomplished?

pattern="([A-z0-9À-ž\s]){2,}"

The input is just a text field that receives the same data over and over. 3 numbers, 1 space, and then a name. I would like to be able to enter that but get back an extra space after the numbers.

For example:
If I enter: "951 Houston"
I would like it to output: "951  Houston" <---extra space after the 3 numbers.

I would like it to be after any characters entered. So if someone were to enter "Houston" it would actually output "Hou ston" Is this possible using the pattern attribute in forms? If so how? If not what is a possible solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex can't add a space, so no, this is not possible with just HTML forms. What you would need to do is first extract the word to replace, then use a regex to split the word into a second word after three characters, then add the result back to the DOM:

```js
var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
var str = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
var replaced = str.replace(/.{3}/g, function (value, index) {
    return value + (index % 5 == 0 ? ' ' : '');
});

textareas[0].value = replaced;
```

```css
input, textarea {
    width:100%
}
```

```html
<input value="Houston"/>
<textarea></textarea>
```

In the above example, the string is extracted from the word in question (`Houston` in an input field, in this case), and `replaced` contains the string that has been broken into two new words. Simply insert it wherever you would like :)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you! Now instead (or possibly in addition to) of adding a space after the first 3 characters is it possible to style the word after the first 3 characters and the space entered into the form? For example making it bold? If you input "903 Houston" You get 903 **Houston** with Houston bolded. Assuming you need to inject HTML tags?